# Add tab Social to Lightning case

Tags: case, lightning-apps

I am trying to add the Social Tab to chatter in the case page see the Image.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this fixed. To add the social tab to will need to do the following:

- Go to setup > Object Manager >Case
- select page layouts and your Case Layout
- in the Case layout select "Mobile & Lightning Actions"
- Select the Social box
- Drag it to the "Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions"
- Quick Save